# Default route add fails, in same subnet

Tags: networking, source-routing, fedora-22

I am running Fedora 22, (Kernel 4.0.4), and trying to add a default route for a custom routing table, **SERVINT** used by vlan30 on the Ethernet interface, enp3s0.

The VLAN has two IP addresses associated with it, being:

**192.168.129.66** & **192.168.129.67**, /29 subnet.

The vlan interface in the routing intelligence (ZyXel 110 firewall) is:

**192.168.129.65** (on the same subnet as the NIC addresses)

After re-booting the server, I clear all the routes and rules using:

*ip route flush cache*

*ip route flush all*

*ip rule flush*

All the rules and routes are removed.

I then add a route:

*ip route add 192.168.129.64/29 dev vlan30  proto static  scope global  src 192.168.129.67  table SERVINT*

So far, all is good. When I go to add the default route to 192.168.129.65, I get **"RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable"**, yet the default route is within the sub-net of the route defined previously.

The only way I can get the default route to be accepted is having it defined as an IP address on the NIC, then of course it will not talk to the routing intelligence, for further routing.... so that is a fail as well.

**Does anyone have an idea as to what might be wrong?**

***TEST UPDATE_25062015***

If I do the above with the VLAN routed in the "main" table (table Nº 254), everything works correctly, but when it is done on the custom table (table Nº 200), the fault is consistent, as described above.

The KERNEL config has CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y, so the multiple tables and Policy Routing functions should be enabled.
The custom table is defined in */etc/iproute2/rt_tables* file.

Is there anything else that will stop the use of custom routing tables?

Cheers,
GM

Comment: You can populate a custom routing table, but if you have no rule to use it, it will not be used. What does `ip a` show? /29 or /32 on your IP address? If /29, then you shouldn't need to add a route for /29 anyway, that should happen automatically.

Comment: The default route for table SERVINT was not even being written to the file, so the presence or lack of applicable rule was not being evaluated.

Comment: Hi Garth, please remove the SOLVED from the question, you will be able to accept your answer in a few hours.

Comment: The forumism of editing titles to say "solved"  stems from the fact that the forum format makes it difficult to mark a question as complete and it is not needed here. In a while you should be able to use the "tick" that is next to your self answer in order to mark it as the correct answer and thus "solve" your question. We have a delay on marking self answers as correct to prevent abuse of the system and to give others a chance to post solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of this particular problem - the  stock Fedora 22 Server install does NOT install some needed files for supporting Multiple Route Tables.

The packages with the missing files are "kernel-headers", "kernel-devel" and "libnl3-devel". Without these packages the fib_rules module will not run.